# Spring Batch with custom FieldSetMapper not saving data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I need to load a big .csv into my database, I have the Price entity that has a reference to a Distributor:

```
public class Price {

@Id
private String id;

private Date dtComu;

private Double price;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idDistributor")
private Distributor distributor;

//constrcutor, getters&setters
```

The csv with Price data that I try to upload has a reference to the Distributor id for each Price. on the ItemReader i have:

```
public FlatFileItemReader<Price> priceReader() {

    FlatFileItemReader<Price> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("file.csv"));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(2);
    reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(recordSeparatorPolicy);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Price>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setStrict(false);
                    setDelimiter(";");
                    setNames(new String[] { "idDistributor", "price", "dtComu" });
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(customMapper());

        }
    });

    return reader;
}
```

And my customMapper is:

```
public class CustomMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Price> {

@Autowired
DistributorRepository repository;

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

@Override
public Price mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    Distributor distributor = repository.findById(fieldSet.readInt("idDistributor")).orElse(null);
    if (distributore == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Price p = new Price();
    p.setDistributor(distributor);
    p.setPrice(fieldSet.readDouble("price"));
    try {
        p.setDtComu(formatter.parse(fieldSet.readString("dtComu")));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        p.setDtComu(new Date());
    }
    //here i will crate an ID for the Price that i need to always be unique
    p.setId(distributor.getIdImpianto()+ fieldSet.readString("dtComu"));
    return p;   }}
```

My Writer is as follows:

```
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Price> prezzoWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<price> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Price>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Prezzo>());
    ;
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO price (id_distributor, price, dt_comu) "
            + "VALUES (:idDistributor, :price, :dtComu");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}
```

I run the program and it completes without anything being saved. Could I be doing something very wrong? I just started with Sring Batch and have to elaborate something a bit complex..

Comment: Which transaction manager are you using?

Comment: hey, im using JPA

Comment: ok that's your issue. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` knows nothing about the JPA context. You need to use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` for this to work.